# Rails, Is there any way in my view use link_to to grab the contents of a specific field and place it in a ruby variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically I am trying to capture the value of the form field before it is saved to the database. Then I intend to use that value in my controller to update a specific field in the database,

> using
>   @taskforms.update_attribute('notes',
>   $notes)

I need to do this because I know of no other way to update that that does not require the full record to be validated.

The suggestion below to use **@taskforms.save(false)** is really not what I was looking for optimally. However it could work. However having and issue to get it to work.

**What I am currently using (that works with validations)**

```
 def myupdate
     @taskforms = Taskforms.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @taskforms.update_attributes(params[:taskforms])
           @taskforms.update_attribute('edited_at', Time.new ) 
           flash[:notice] = 'Note was successfully updated.'
           format.html { redirect_to(:controller => "taskforms", :action => "displayedit", :id =>  @taskforms.id) }
           format.xml  { head :ok }
        else
           format.html { render :action => "displayedit" }
           format.xml  { render :xml =>  @taskforms.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
  end
```

**However when I try the save(false) it doesn't save** and triggers validations anyway

```
def myupdate
     @taskforms = Taskforms.find(params[:id])
       if  @taskforms.save(false)
          @taskforms.update_attribute('edited_at', Time.new ) 
          flash[:notice] = 'Note was successfully updated.'
          format.html { redirect_to(:controller => "taskforms", :action => "displayedit", :id =>  @taskforms.id) }
          format.xml  { head :ok }
       else
          format.html { render :action => "displayedit" }
          format.xml  { render :xml =>  @taskforms.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
   end
end
```

I have never used **Save** in the past just the default **respond_to do |format|** so suspect my code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`@taskforms.save(false)` will save your model without any validations if that is your main goal.